# Android Achartengine Bar Chart Value Format

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there way I can change the bar chart value from something like 1000000 to $1,000,000 (value at the top of the bar)? I didn't find a way to set this value as string.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html it has methods to set custom x and y labels

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do.

Set the number formatter

```
mRenderer.setLabelFormat(new DecimalFormat("#,###"));
```

Set axis title

```
mRenderer.setYTitle("Values in $");
```

Or you could try this method of XYMultipleSeriesRenderer

```
addYTextLabel(double yValue, java.lang.String text, int the rendererScale)
```

Try setting '$1,000,000' as the second argument and check the output. I haven't tried it before. Give it go and see if that helps.